# Dynamic filtering in EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to create a database with the following entity object `Person` in a .NET 8 project. I have setup EF core and I can use the basic CRUD operations on this `Person` table. What I want is to give the user of my program to view all users in the database and filter on this user on its properties. The user should be able to filter on the Name and on the Created timestamp.

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

So I have created the following method:

```cs
public async Task<List<Person>> GetFilteredKeysetPagination(int lastId, int take)
{
    using ApplicationDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();

    var lastWeek = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(7);

    return await context.Persons
        .OrderByDescending(l => l.Timestamp)
        .ThenByDescending(l => l.Id)
        .Where(l => l.Id <= lastId)
        .Where(l => l.Name.Contains("Test"))
        .Where(l => l.Created < DateTime.Now)
        .Where(l => l.Created > lastWeek)
        .Take(take)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

This works but I don't like the `Where` statements that are written because when the user doesn't want to filter the Created property for instance you want to create a query without the two last wheres: *(by the way the `lastId` is a property coming from front-end to make use of keyset pagination)*

```cs
public async Task<List<Person>> GetFilteredKeysetPagination(int lastId, int take)
{
    using ApplicationDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();

    var lastWeek = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(7);

    return await context.Persons
        .OrderByDescending(l => l.Timestamp)
        .ThenByDescending(l => l.Id)
        .Where(l => l.Id <= lastId)
        .Where(l => l.Name.Contains("Test"))
        .Take(take)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

I have tried following to make this query with dynamic filters:

```cs
public async Task<List<Person>> GetFilteredKeysetPagination(int lastId, int take)
{
    using ApplicationDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();

    var lastWeek = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(7);

    var query = context.Persons
        .OrderByDescending(l => l.Timestamp)
        .ThenByDescending(l => l.Id)
        .Where(l => l.Id <= lastId);

    if (_filters.IsNameFilterEnabled)
    {
        query = query.Where(l => l.Name.Contains(_filters.NameFilterValue));
    }
    if (_filters.IsCreatedFilterEnabled)
    {
        query = query.Where(l => l.Created < DateTime.Now);
        query = query.Where(l => l.Created > lastWeek);
    }

    return query.Take(take)
                .ToListAsync();
}
```

But this gives the following exception when run:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Person>()
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Created)
    .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(
        value: __filter_0, 
        comparisonType: OrdinalIgnoreCase))' could not be translated. 

Additional information: Translation of method 'string.Contains' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Is the approach I have in any way possible? Or should I simply write out all queries for all possible filter combination scenarios? I prefer **not** to use [MethodToSqlMapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping#mapping-a-method-to-a-custom-sql)

*Please note that class names are manually changed to make explanation less complex. If more information is required I can provide this! Cheers*

Comment: Nothing suspicious is shown, should work. Try comment out filter by filter and understand which part is not translatable.

Comment: The issue occurs directly when I enable the `NameFilter` and comment the other filter. EF core doesn't seem to like the separation of the LINQ .Where statements..

Comment: The error message says that the translation of the String.Contains is the issue. How does the comparisonType Parameter get added? I believe that is the culprit that EF can't handle, but I don't see where it comes from with the code you posted here

Comment: I do not see `OrdinalIgnoreCase` in your sample. Probably you have forgot to put it here?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv @JineappleAre I don't know how the `OrdinalIgnoreCase` is added to the query. I did not add the comparisonType parameter in the contains method so I think it is put there by default? I'm using EF-core 8.0.0 with Sqlite database.

Comment: @County `_filters.NameFilterValue` what is this? a string field should work (property with setter/getter is may cause complication). chaining `Where` inside `if`s should not be the issue, it was what [fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) meant to be used.

Comment: @BagusTesa `_filters.NameFilterValue` is a simple getter setter string property. Replacing this with a hardcoded string still gives the same exception.

Comment: I guess you have to do a slow step by step transformation from the query that works to what you want and see at what point it stops working with a hardcoded string. Somehow, at some point the OrdinalIgnoreCase gets added....

Comment: Install [ReadableExpressionsVisualizers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers) and analyze after each step `query.Expression`

Comment: @County *"replacing it with a hardcoded string still give the same exception"* - thats odd, your first tries without `if` block (the direct `.Where` chaining) works right? try making that one. if it also doesnt work, something is horribly wrong. [`string.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions) should be already well-mapped in ef core 8, afaik they already were since ef core 2.